# React not changing UseState when socket io is receiving message it only works when I refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

I have created social media app with chat when I send message from one user to another chat never updates with new message until I refresh bot users and texting becomes normal and works fine but when I try to text without refreshing it won't work. Even when text does not change sometimes I get console log with message that I sent from one user to another. Console log (data) is  working most of the time but setArrivalMessage is never triggered for some reason until I refresh bot pages.

This is picture of console.log that I am getting (sometimes I even do not get console log)
[image]

```
useEffect(() => { 
    socket.current.on("getMessage", (data) => {
        setArrivalMessage({ 
           
           
            sender: data.senderId,
            text: data.text,
            createdAt: Date.now(),
        })
    })
},[])

useEffect(() => {
    
    arrivalMessage &&
      currentChat?.members.includes(arrivalMessage.sender) &&
      setMessages((prev) => [...prev, arrivalMessage]);
  }, [arrivalMessage, currentChat]);
```

Comment: At the very least you need to provide a 'cleanup' function because every time `currentChat` changes you are going to register more event handlers and they never go away.

Comment: The way I read this code is:  whenever currentChat changes, add a new event listener on socket.  Not sure why you need more than one event listener set.

Comment: @Evert I have re edited my question, can you check it out again?

Comment: @James I have re edited my question, can you check it out again?

Comment: Please provide a sample of `data` (from your console.log)

Comment: @James I am having issue right now even console.log(data) wont trigger. For some reason it won't work until I refresh whole page but when I do that messages are working fine. Any soulution?

Comment: @James for some reason console.log is working again but no messages are displayed. I have added picture above.

Comment: Does `currentChat` need to be a dependency? Is it state or a prop ?

Comment: @NiceBooks currentChat is a state. I have deleted [currentChat] it is now empty and it is same thing as before. I think that [] should be empty but bug is not fixed.

Comment: @Evert I have deleted currentChat it should be empty [] but I am still getting same issue

Comment: Is the socket event correct: `getMessage` ?

Comment: Why is it `socket.current` ? Is the socket a ref ?

Comment: @NiceBooks Yes socket is ref and here is code from back end (getMessage) : 

https://snipboard.io/grsOfY.jpg
everything from socket io server side should be correct.

Comment: Please post the entire component code if possible.

Comment: @NiceBooks Here are screenshots of whole Chat component and Socket Io components:
https://snipboard.io/3M28xA.jpg 
https://snipboard.io/xPnlC2.jpg 
https://snipboard.io/4tcTJr.jpg 
https://snipboard.io/4C0T61.jpg 
https://snipboard.io/jf3n4w.jpg 
https://snipboard.io/3M28xA.jpg

Comment: Cannot see render part of component. Please post entire component in question itself, or atleast a codesandbox.

Comment: @NiceBooks Here is link of sandbox with whole code of both components if you need more components let me know so I can upload them. Thank you for trying to help me! 
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-leakey-hpzbbr?file=/src/Chat.jsx

Comment: @James I have posted code in sandbox can you check it?